# how to show multiple message using react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to show multiple message using provider and hooks . But I am not able to show multiple message .One one message is show at one time don't know why ?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/new-mountain-cnkye5?file=/src/App.tsx:274-562

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      utilContext.addMessage("error 2 sec");
    }, 300);

    setTimeout(() => {
      utilContext.addMessage("error 5 mili sec");
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      utilContext.addMessage("error 1  sec");
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

I am also using map function to render all message.

```
 return (
    <>
      {messages.map((msg, index) => (
        <div key={`Toast-Message-${index}`}>
          {msg.msg}
          <button
            onClick={(event) => {
              alert("000");
            }}
          >
            close
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}

      <ConfirmationDialogContext.Provider value={value}>
        {children}
      </ConfirmationDialogContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
```

**Expected output** : It will show 3 messages after some time.

Comment: What does `addMessage`'s code look like? Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Also, beware of using an index as a key if the array changes. It works if the array **only ever grows without previous elements changing**, but doesn't work correctly if you remove elements from the array or change them. More in [this post](https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/) linked from [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Comment: *here is my code https://codesandbox.io/s/new-mountain-cnkye5?file=/src/App.tsx:274-562"*  The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put all necessary code **in** the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your

```
const addMessage = (message: string, status: "success" | "error") => {
    setmessages([...messages, { msg: message, type: status, duration: 5000 }]);
  };
```

to

```
  const addMessage = (message: string, status: "success" | "error") => {
    setmessages((currentMessages) => [
      ...currentMessages,
      { msg: message, type: status, duration: 5000 }
    ]);
  };
```

This is because you call the 3 `addMessage` in the same time, and so the `messages` variable has the same value in all three calls.

Read [Updating state based on the previous state](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) for more info on this syntax

Comment: There are plenty of previous questions and answers covering stale state.

Answer (score 0):

You context is changing every time you add a message, and in your `useEffect` dependencies you don't have the context as a dep. which means that you're only adding messages to the first context instance, while rendering the latest one all the time.

BUT, if you add the context to your `useEffect` dependencies you will get an infinite loop.

One (**Bad**) solution would be to track every `setTimeout` with `useRef` like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const utilContext = useConfirmationDialog();
  const m1Ref = React.useRef(false);
  const m2Ref = React.useRef(false);
  const m3Ref = React.useRef(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
    const s = [];
    if (m1Ref.current === false) {
      const s1 = setTimeout(() => {
        utilContext.addMessage("error 300 msec");
      }, 300);
      s.push(s1);
      m1Ref.current = true;
    }
    
    if (m2Ref.current === false) {
      const s2 = setTimeout(() => {
        m2Ref.current = true;
        utilContext.addMessage("error 2 sec");
      }, 2000);
      s.push(s2);
    }
    
    if (m3Ref.current === false) {
      const s3 = setTimeout(() => {
        m3Ref.current = true;
        utilContext.addMessage("error 1  sec");
      }, 1000);
      s.push(s3);
    }

    return () => {
      s.forEach((x) => clearTimeout(x));
    };
  }, [utilContext]);
  
  return (
    <Typography>
      MUI example. Please put the code to reproduce the issue in src/App.tsx
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

I think that you should move the delay of presenting the messages out of the sender into the context, like this:

```
  const addMessage = (delay: number, message: string, status: "success" | "error") => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setmessages((currentMessages) => [
        ...currentMessages,
        { msg: message, type: status, duration: 5000 }
      ]);
    }, delay);
  };
```